Unable to read and write downloaded file using puppeteer inside AWS Lamda function
I am trying to download a file which is .CSV, using puppeteer with AWS Lamda. Everything else is working fine, I am checking AWS CLOUDWATCH LOGS to see the errors and debugging statements logs.
I am getting error which is "Can't find the file I downloaded"... I don't know even the file has been downloaded or not. I know that in AWS Lamda there is "/tmp" which is temporarily used for file system.
So now, what I want is to locate the downloaded file properly so that I can upload the downloaded file to my S3 bucket.
I have already all required permissions to upload files to S3 bucket.
I tried localhost before this and that worked well, however I had got some errors regarding file paths on localhost too, but I solved that and successfully uploaded the downloaded file to AWS S3.
Now, I need your help to do the same using AWS Lamda.
Thanks
import { launch } from "puppeteer";
import chromium from "@sparticuz/chromium";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";


const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: "us-east-1" });

async function uploadFileToS3(filePath) {
  try {
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const formattedDate = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
      month: "2-digit",
      day: "2-digit",
      year: "numeric",
    });
    const uploadParams = {
      Bucket: "my-bucket",
      Key:  `Report ${formattedDate}.csv`,
      Body: fileContent,
    };

    const command = new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams);
    await s3Client.send(command);
    console.log("File uploaded successfully to S3");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error uploading file to S3:", err);
  }
}

function delay(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);
  });
}

async function waitForDashboardLoad(page) {
  let maxAttempts = 30;
  let attempt = 0;
  while (attempt < maxAttempts) {
    try {
      await page.waitForSelector("#dashpageNav", { timeout: 10000 });

      await page.waitForSelector("#header", {
        timeout: 5000,
      });

      await page.waitForSelector("#showTabLeft", { timeout: 3000 });
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      // Dashboard not fully loaded yet, continue polling
      attempt++;
      console.log(`Attempt ${attempt}: Dashboard not loaded yet, retrying...`);
      await delay(5000); // Wait for 5 seconds before retrying
    }
  }
  console.log("Dashboard did not load within the specified timeout.");
  return false; // Dashboard did not load within the maximum attempts
}

async function waitForCustomerLoad(page) {
  let maxAttempts = 20;
  let attempt = 0;
  while (attempt < maxAttempts) {
    try {
      await page.waitForSelector("#customerReportTable_wrapper", {
        timeout: 10000,
      });

      await page.waitForSelector(".showMenuButton", {
        timeout: 5000,
      });

      return true; // Customer loaded successfully
    } catch (error) {
      // Customer not fully loaded yet, continue polling
      attempt++;
      console.log(
        `Attempt ${attempt}: Customer page not loaded yet, retrying...`
      );
      await delay(5000); // Wait for 5 seconds before retrying
    }
  }
  console.log("Customer page did not load within the specified timeout.");
  return false;
}

export async function handler(event) {
  const browser = await launch({
    // headless: false,
    //require to run on aws lambda
    args: chromium.args,
    executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
  });

  // Opening a new page in the browser
  const page = (await browser.pages())[0];

  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(120000 * 2);



  const client = await page.createCDPSession();
  const downloadDirectory = ("tmp");
  await client.send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
    behavior: "allow",
    downloadPath: downloadDirectory,
  });

  await page.goto("https://mywebsite.com/");
  await page.waitForSelector("#inputUser");
  await delay(3000);

  await page.type("#inputUser", "user", delay(10));

  await page.type('input[type="password"]', "password", delay(10));

  await page.click("input.green-button");
  await delay(3000);

  const isDashboardLoaded = await waitForDashboardLoad(page);
  if (!isDashboardLoaded) {
    console.error("Dashboard failed to load within the specified timeout.");
    await browser.close();
    return;
  }

  await page.click("#showTabLeft");
  await delay(2000);

  await page.click("#customerLink");

  await delay(2000);

  const isCustomerLoaded = await waitForCustomerLoad(page);
  if (!isCustomerLoaded) {
    console.error("Customer page failed to load within the specified timeout.");
    await browser.close();
    return;
  }

  await page.click(".showMenuButton");

  await delay(2000);

  await page.click("li[for='soldCustomers'").catch((e) => console.log(e));

  await delay(2000);

  await page.waitForSelector("#soldForm").catch((e) => console.log(e));

  await page
    .click('input[name="soldCustomersReportDateFilter"]')
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));

  await delay(1000);

  await page
    .waitForSelector(
      ".daterangepicker.dropdown-menu.ltr.openscenter.show-calendar",
      { timeout: 5000 }
    )
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));

  await delay(1000);

  await page
    .waitForSelector(
      ".daterangepicker.dropdown-menu.ltr.openscenter.show-calendar .ranges ul li:nth-child(7)",
      { timeout: 3000 }
    )
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));

  await page
    .click(
      ".daterangepicker.dropdown-menu.ltr.openscenter.show-calendar .ranges ul li:nth-child(7)"
    )
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));

  await delay(4000);

  await page
    .waitForSelector("select[name='employeeTypes']", { timeout: 5000 })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));

  await page.click("select[name='employeeTypes']").catch((e) => console.log(e));

  await page
    .select('select[name="employeeTypes"]', "-1")
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));

  await delay(1000);

 //..here is where the button got clicked to download the file
  await page
    .click(".col-12.rightEnd .tableButton:nth-child(2)")
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));

  await delay(8000);
  
  
  const fileName = "Report.csv";
  const filePath = path.join(downloadDirectory, fileName);
  

  
  // Call function to upload file to S3
  await uploadFileToS3(filePath);

  await browser.close();
  
  return JSON.stringify({
    message: "File uploaded to S3 Bucket",
    dir: downloadDirectory,
    filePathDir: filePath,
    
  })
}


Error I got inside AWS CLOUD WATCH LOGS:
2024-05-04T10:10:21.054Z    ba448632-3e73-4e49-8368-584d516b1f10    ERROR   Error uploading file to S3: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'tmp/Report.csv'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:582:18)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:461:35)
    at uploadFileToS3 (file:///var/task/index.mjs:13:28)
    at Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.mjs:211:9) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'tmp/Report.csv'
} 

Response I get when I invoke the function URL:
{
    "message": "File uploaded to S3 Bucket",
    "dir": "/var/task/tmp",
    "filePathDir": "/var/task/tmp/Report.csv"
}

This is what I already tried:
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
  const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

  const client = await page.createCDPSession();
  const downloadDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, "tmp");
  await client.send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
    behavior: "allow",
    downloadPath: downloadDirectory,
  });

and

const fileName = "Report.csv";
const filePath = path.join("tmp", fileName);
await uploadFileToS3(filePath);



Solution:
I changed this line of code:
  const downloadDirectory = ("tmp");

to
  const downloadDirectory = ("/tmp");

Also make sure you have following IAM role permissions while working with Lamda functions with S3:

AmazonS3FullAccess
AWSLambdaEdgeExecutionRole

